# Spring Dependency Injection Security

Tags: spring

I'm just curious to know whether the usage of spring dependency injection in applications would at any time cause any security issues. Is the framework secure? or is there any discrepancy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't cause any security issue. And `dependency injection` is for `loose coupling` of components. The framework is completely secure, and in today's world 2/3rd of `enterprise applications` are developed in `Spring`.

Comment: Thanks. I read in OWASP Top 10 Critical Web Application Security Risks that if the security settings of the development frameworks like struts and spring are not set appropriately, it would cause Security Misconfiguration which takes the Top 5th position.

Comment: That is for every framework. Every framework have security settings for unauthorized access, like `Spring` provides `Spring Security`.

Comment: `Struts` have its own way. Read their tutorials or official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Not an inherent security issue but you could introduce one. Keep in mind, most security flaws are due to code you write, not a framework you are using. That said, I've used spring and spring security and both can have a very large learning curve which, if done incorrectly, could cause security problems. Given the complexity, you absolutely can EASILY, unknowingly, introduce security problems to your application. Spring, in and of itself, is not 'insecure', but given it's complexity (spring security is HORRIBLY complex IMO), it can allow you to make mistakes and open yourself up to possible exploits.